# Can the community vote out a block producer any minute?

Tags: block-producer, vote-decay

In this blog post, [Dan Larimer](https://medium.com/eosio/introducing-eosio-dawn-4-0-f738c552879) says, "In order to maintain maximum voting influence each voter will have to re-assert their vote every week."

Does this mean that a voter can only change her vote once every week? If so, what if a BP turns into a bad actor right after winning the community's faith? Or can token holders vote out a BP any time they wish to?

Answer (score 3):

I think that like in Steem, voters may change their BP votes as often as they wish (subject to bandwidth limits). Perhaps the vote decay operation runs once a week though, so to ensure your vote is never in a decayed state, you would need to reassert it that frequently. I haven't checked the code to confirm this though.

Answer (score 2):

Votes are examined every "round" (every 2 minutes and 6 seconds, i.e. after each of the 21 active producers has had their turn to make their 12 blocks in their assigned 6-second window) to see who should be making blocks next round.

So the lineup can change at that frequency.

As a voter you can call the `voteproducer` command as often as you like, within the normal rate limits of the system, i.e. depending on how many tokens you've staked for bandwidth and CPU.

Answer (score 0):

they can vote them out every 3 days